# Is there any proverb for the expression to "do things in a passive way"?

Tags: phrase-requests, proverb-requests

What is the proverb for the expression "Do things in a passive way" or "playing safe"?

For instance, suppose, someone Mr X wants that Mr Y, and Mr Z both quits the job as he doesn't like either of them. So, he devises a strategy. He knows that Mr Y is in bad terms with Mr Z. So, he passively agitates Mr Y against Mr Z and vice versa. One day, either Mr Y or Mr Z loses his temper and hits the other one with a chair, and thereby both of them lose their jobs.

I think there is an English proverb for this.

Comment: What have you discovered from your own searches/research? For example, the first two resources in the _Idioms, expressions and slang_ section of [What good reference works on English are available?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available)

Comment: Are you sure you want a proverb?  A proverb is generally something that offers advice, not just a phrase to describe an action or situation.

Answer (score 1):

There is a phrasal verb "to play off against".

Mr. X played Mr. Y off against Mr. Z.

http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/play+off+against, drawn 
from the McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs.

Answer (score 0):

Not a proverb, but a good idiom to describe this behavior is [*pulling the strings.*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pull+the+strings)

> to control the actions of a person or group, often secretly

So, you could say:

> Sure, Mr. Z got himself fired but it was Mr. X pulling the strings.

The verb *undermine*, which literally means "to dig a hole underneath," would work well here too.

Comment: But in your example, Mr. Z succeeds in getting them fired. I'm confused.

Comment: Pullin Strings mean, making someone work like a pawn.

Comment: Uh… *Pulling the strings* means making someone work like a *puppet*, anonymous; a string puppet or marionette.

I was confused by your apparent comparison of *doing things in a passive way* to *playing safe* which first led to me to think your *passive* way might equate to *sitting on the fence* 

I don't think you'll find many another example where *doing things in a passive way* includes *passively* agitating anyone against another

Comment: I was mostly basing my answer on the example.